# Import Excel to SharePoint list -> Auto-synchonize based on Id

Tags: list, excel, sync

Are there tools available for importing an Excel file to a SharePoint list so that the importing data would be synchronized based on specified field(s)?
I would mostly be interested in a non-commercial solution.

EDIT: Ended up writing a custom solution:

1. Read rows from Excel via OpenXML
2. Match an id column to similar SharePoint field

Web UI has a couple of steps:

1. Browse for Excel
2. Preview changes
3. Synchronize

Excel parsing was pretty simple. Synchronizing to SharePoint also would be pretty straightforward (if not aiming for a lot of generalization).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Option 1](https://www.softfluent.com/product/sharePoint-list-synchronizer/): A free solution that requires that you create the SharePoint list in Excel, requires an Excel plug-in (released by Microsoft) and requires that you save in the 2003 xls format to retain the sync.

[Option 2](http://www.softfluent.com/xlsync.aspx): A very inexpensive solution similar to the first but does not require you to create the SharePoint list in Excel first. Has an API.

[Option 3](http://www.layer2.de/en/products/Pages/SharePoint-Business-Data-List-Connector.aspx): A wildly effective solution with nearly no limitations.  Unfortunately, it is comparatively very expensive. Has an API.

Comment: We ended up doing a custom import/export/synchronize solution.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an option to do this out of the box. Check out using the BDC?

Comment: Datasheet view should be supported, and the data is not linked to a specific table: users should also be able to import other files (or excels) to the list.

Comment: you can copy and paste rows from an excel file into a datasheet view. You were asking for a synchronized solution, datasheet view isn't it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this option: (Requires an Excel plugin)

Publishing and Synchronizing Excel 2007 Tables to SharePoint Lists
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb462636(v=office.11).aspx

It supports having Date and Text columns as per my memory. More column types may be supported, but I am not sure.

Comment: Thanks but this Excel 2003 related solution was not an option for us..